# Binary Search C++, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search

the thing is that we are tring to do for first time a binary search function for a vector class, but I dont really know the reason why this is not working. Does anyone know what could be wrong(Status acces violation when the number is not in the vector array)??

// size_ is de number of used elements i the array

```
  int Vector::bsearch(int value) const
  {
    int first = 0;
    int last = size_ - 1;
    int Substraction = size_ /2;

    while(last >= first)
    {
      Substraction = first + (last - first) / 2;

      if(array_[Substraction] > value)
        last = Substraction;

      else if(array_[Substraction] < value)
        first = Substraction;

      else if(array_[Substraction] == value)
        return Substraction;
    }
    return CS170::Vector::NO_INDEX;
  }
```

//SOLVED

```
  int Vector::bsearch(int value) const
  {
    unsigned first = 0;
    unsigned last = size_ - 1;
    unsigned int mid;

    if(value < array_[0] || value > array_[size_ - 1])
      return CS170::Vector::NO_INDEX;

    while(last >= first)
    {
      mid = first + (last - first) / 2;

      if(value < array_[mid])
        last = mid - 1;

      else if(array_[mid] < value)
        first = mid + 1;

      else
        return mid;
    }
    return CS170::Vector::NO_INDEX;
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps `int last = first = 0;` has something to do with it, who knows. Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: Why the annoying '  _ ' suffix for the size_  and array_ variable names?

Comment: In your fixed code, you might need to check for `size_ == 0` in case someone's removed all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not excluding the element you just tested before the next loop. And your choice of variable names, `Subtraction` is dreadful. Its a *midpoint*.

```
int first = 0;
int last = size_-1;
int mid = 0;

while(last >= first)
{
    mid = first + (last - first) / 2;

    if(value < array_[mid])
        last = mid-1; // don't include element just tested

    else if(array_[mid] < value)
        first = mid+1; // don't include element just tested

    else return mid;
}
return CS170::Vector::NO_INDEX
```

Comment: now it just gives status access when the number is not in the vector array

Comment: do u have any idea why?? I changed the variable name, it's true, it was not a good name

Comment: Not sure what the problem was, but the original answer incorrectly limited last to size_, which for your algorithm was wrong. it should be correct as posted now. glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization is wrong -

```
int first = size_ - 1;
int last = first = 0;
```

should be -

```
int last = size_ - 1;
int first = 0;
```

Also, in `while` you should use the following condition -

```
while (last>first)
```

Comment: i changed the while, but still infinite loop

Comment: @user3239445 remove `=` sign